# How to send a $var with ajax and POST?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How would I go about sending "$var" to "doc.php", and how would "doc.php" read it? As $_POST['$var'] or $var?

Here is what I'm using:

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

// Is .done what I want to post upon page load-up?

```
$('').done(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "doc.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          Variable: <?php print $var; ?>,
        },
        success: function (m) {
            console.log(m);
        },
        error: function (e) {
          console.log("Something went wrong ...: "+e.message);
        },
      }); /* end ajax*/
      e.preventDefault();
    });
    </script>
```

Also, I'm trying to submit on page load. Obviously this is not working, and there is more to the code--but I wanted to keep it simple. How do you "POST" just like you would in HTML --in the background, and without a button(just on page load)?

Answer (score 2):

doc.php would read it as `$_POST["Variable"]`

You send it by Ajax in the following structure:

```
data: { variable: 'desired_value' }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you wrap the ***value*** in the object literal in quotes if the value is not an integer:

```
data: { Variable: '<?php print $var; ?>'}
```

Comment: So, on "doc.php" do I have to somehow pull this function out by doing something like: <?php $newvar = $_post['var'] ... or is $_post['var] supposed to be enough? Also, is there any way can I tell if this info is being forwarded to doc.php--since I cant actually see it being ran?

Comment: echoing `$_post['var]` in the manner above, with quotes, should be all that is needed. do a viewsource to test whether the value has been outputted properly to the page ...

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery document ready function to do something after the page is loaded.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       var valuetToSend= '<?php echo $var; ?>';
        $.ajax({
            url: "doc.php",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: { Variable: valuetToSend },
            success: function (m) {
                alert(m);
            },
            error: function (e) {
              alert("Something went wrong ...: "+e.message);
            },
          }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Would this code also run doc.php, or only post the values over to it, expecting to be refreshed and ran in some other way? It looks like this might be working, but my "doc.php" is the one with a mysql insert command.

Comment: @myladeybugg: This will execute the doc.php. We are passing a variable called "Varaibale" with the value we read from the PHP page. The doc.php page can read he value and execute whatever code it has.if you return some value from doc.php. It will be available in the `m` variable which you have in success event